# Streaming RTP packets using SDP to ffmpeg

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, rtp, sdp

I have RTP packets in node.js server and I want to forward them to ffmpeg.
I generate SDP files in the node.js server side and execute ffmpeg with the SDP as input.

SDP:

```
v=0
o=mediasoup 21881725401d4e8d56cbd79694c7e2b6e6cacb4a 0 IN IP4 192.168.193.182
s=21881725401d4e8d56cbd79694c7e2b6e6cacb4a
c=IN IP4 192.168.193.182
t=0 0
a=group:LS video audio
m=video 33404 RTP/SAVPF 107
a=rtpmap:107 H264/90000
a=fmtp:107 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42e01f
a=control:track0
a=rtcp-fb:107 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:107 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:107 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:107 goog-remb 
a=rtcp-fb:107 transport-cc 
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:4 urn:3gpp:video-orientation
a=extmap:5 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=extmap:6 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay
a=mid:video
a=sendrecv
m=audio 33402 RTP/SAVPF 111
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000
a=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
a=control:track1
a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc 
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=mid:audio
a=sendrecv
```

Command:

```
ffmpeg -max_delay 5000 -reorder_queue_size 16384 -protocol_whitelist file,crypto,udp,rtp -re -i input.sdp -vcodec copy -acodec aac -y output.mp4
```

Same with RTMP

```
ffmpeg -max_delay 5000 -reorder_queue_size 16384 -protocol_whitelist file,crypto,udp,rtp -re -i input.sdp -vcodec copy -acodec aac -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/myStream
```

I get weird video that plays some vidoe, then get stuck, then plays some audio, back to video and so on, it never plays both video and audio together.

BTW, when I created separate SDP files for the video and the audio and stream them as two inputs into the same output, I get valid stream but the audio is not in sync (about a second offset).

```
ffmpeg -max_delay 5000 -reorder_queue_size 16384 -protocol_whitelist file,crypto,udp,rtp -re -i video.0.sdp -max_delay 5000 -reorder_queue_size 16384 -protocol_whitelist file,crypto,udp,rtp -re -i audio.1.sdp -vcodec copy -acodec aac -shortest -y output.mp4
```

What is wrong with my SDP?

I tried changing analyzeduration, probesize, rtbufsize, vsync, framerate,
I even tried to remap the streams using -map 0:v -map 0:a, 
nothing helped

I also tried to use RTSP server, see log:

```
ffmpeg version 3.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)
  configuration: --prefix=/opt/kaltura/ffmpeg-3.2 --libdir=/opt/kaltura/ffmpeg-3.2/lib --shlibdir=/opt/kaltura/ffmpeg-3.2/lib --extra-cflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fPIC' --extra-cflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fPIC -I/opt/kaltura/include' --extra-ldflags=-L/opt/kaltura/lib --disable-devices --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-avisynth --enable-libxvid --enable-filter=movie --enable-avfilter --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libspeex --enable-libass --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --enable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --disable-debug --disable-optimizations --enable-gpl --enable-pthreads --enable-swscale --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --disable-devices --enable-filter=movie --enable-version3 --enable-indev=lavfi --enable-x11grab
  libavutil      55. 34.100 / 55. 34.100
  libavcodec     57. 64.100 / 57. 64.100
  libavformat    57. 56.100 / 57. 56.100
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-loglevel' ... matched as option 'loglevel' (set logging level) with argument 'debug'.
Reading option '-max_delay' ... matched as AVOption 'max_delay' with argument '500000'.
Reading option '-reorder_queue_size' ... matched as AVOption 'reorder_queue_size' with argument '16384'.
Reading option '-analyzeduration' ... matched as AVOption 'analyzeduration' with argument '2147483647'.
Reading option '-probesize' ... matched as AVOption 'probesize' with argument '2147483647'.
Reading option '-protocol_whitelist' ... matched as AVOption 'protocol_whitelist' with argument 'file,crypto,tcp,udp,rtp'.
Reading option '-re' ... matched as option 're' (read input at native frame rate) with argument '1'.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input file with argument 'rtsp://192.168.193.182:5000/IcL8tHJdU9oWEK3rAAAA.sdp'.
Reading option '-vcodec' ... matched as option 'vcodec' (force video codec ('copy' to copy stream)) with argument 'h264'.
Reading option '-acodec' ... matched as option 'acodec' (force audio codec ('copy' to copy stream)) with argument 'aac'.
Reading option '-max_interleave_delta' ... matched as AVOption 'max_interleave_delta' with argument '30000000'.
Reading option '-y' ... matched as option 'y' (overwrite output files) with argument '1'.
Reading option '/opt/mediasoup_sample/recordings/IcL8tHJdU9oWEK3rAAAA.mp4' ... matched as output file.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option loglevel (set logging level) with argument debug.
Applying option y (overwrite output files) with argument 1.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input file rtsp://192.168.193.182:5000/IcL8tHJdU9oWEK3rAAAA.sdp.
Applying option re (read input at native frame rate) with argument 1.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: rtsp://192.168.193.182:5000/IcL8tHJdU9oWEK3rAAAA.sdp.
[rtsp @ 0x19b4fa0] SDP:
v=0
o=mediasoup IcL8tHJdU9oWEK3rAAAA 0 IN IP4 192.168.193.182
s=IcL8tHJdU9oWEK3rAAAA
c=IN IP4 192.168.193.182
t=0 0
a=group:LS audio video
m=audio 0 RTP/SAVPF 111
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000
a=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
a=control:streamid=0
a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc 
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=mid:audio
a=sendrecv
a=rtcp-mux
m=video 0 RTP/SAVPF 107
a=rtpmap:107 H264/90000
a=fmtp:107 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42e01f
a=control:streamid=1
a=rtcp-fb:107 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:107 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:107 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:107 goog-remb 
a=rtcp-fb:107 transport-cc 
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:4 urn:3gpp:video-orientation
a=extmap:5 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=extmap:6 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay
a=mid:video
a=sendrecv
a=rtcp-mux

[rtsp @ 0x19b4fa0] audio codec set to: opus
[rtsp @ 0x19b4fa0] audio samplerate set to: 48000
[rtsp @ 0x19b4fa0] audio channels set to: 1
[rtsp @ 0x19b4fa0] video codec set to: h264
[rtsp @ 0x19b4fa0] RTP Packetization Mode: 1
[rtsp @ 0x19b4fa0] RTP Profile IDC: 42 Profile IOP: e0 Level: 1f
[udp @ 0x19b5d60] end receive buffer size reported is 131072
[udp @ 0x19ba020] end receive buffer size reported is 131072
[rtsp @ 0x19b4fa0] setting jitter buffer size to 16384
[udp @ 0x19b7a00] end receive buffer size reported is 131072
[udp @ 0x19daca0] end receive buffer size reported is 131072
[rtsp @ 0x19b4fa0] setting jitter buffer size to 16384
[rtsp @ 0x19b4fa0] hello state=0
[h264 @ 0x19b9ac0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x19b9ac0] nal_unit_type: 5, nal_ref_idc: 3
    Last message repeated 3 times
[h264 @ 0x19b9ac0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x19b9ac0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x19b9ac0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x19b9ac0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x19b9ac0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x19b9ac0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x19b9ac0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x19b9ac0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x19b9ac0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x19b9ac0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x19b9ac0] nal_unit_type: 9, nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 0x19b9ac0] nal_unit_type: 1, nal_ref_idc: 3
    Last message repeated 3 times
[h264 @ 0x19b9ac0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x19b9ac0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x19b9ac0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x19b9ac0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x19b9ac0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x19b9ac0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x19b9ac0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x19b9ac0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x19b9ac0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x19b9ac0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x19b9ac0] nal_unit_type: 9, nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 0x19b9ac0] nal_unit_type: 1, nal_ref_idc: 3
    Last message repeated 3 times

    ... a lot of the same ...

[h264 @ 0x19b9ac0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x19b9ac0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x19b9ac0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x19b9ac0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x19b9ac0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x19b9ac0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x19b9ac0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x19b9ac0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x19b9ac0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x19b9ac0] nal_unit_type: 9, nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 0x19b9ac0] nal_unit_type: 7, nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x19b9ac0] nal_unit_type: 8, nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x19b9ac0] nal_unit_type: 5, nal_ref_idc: 3
    Last message repeated 3 times
[h264 @ 0x19b9ac0] Reinit context to 640x480, pix_fmt: yuv420p
[h264 @ 0x19b9ac0] nal_unit_type: 9, nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 0x19b9ac0] nal_unit_type: 1, nal_ref_idc: 3
    Last message repeated 3 times
[h264 @ 0x19b9ac0] nal_unit_type: 9, nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 0x19b9ac0] nal_unit_type: 1, nal_ref_idc: 3
    Last message repeated 3 times
[h264 @ 0x19b9ac0] nal_unit_type: 9, nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 0x19b9ac0] nal_unit_type: 1, nal_ref_idc: 3
    Last message repeated 3 times
[h264 @ 0x19b9ac0] nal_unit_type: 9, nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 0x19b9ac0] nal_unit_type: 1, nal_ref_idc: 3
    Last message repeated 3 times
[h264 @ 0x19b9ac0] nal_unit_type: 9, nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 0x19b9ac0] nal_unit_type: 1, nal_ref_idc: 3
    Last message repeated 3 times
[h264 @ 0x19b9ac0] nal_unit_type: 9, nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 0x19b9ac0] nal_unit_type: 1, nal_ref_idc: 3
    Last message repeated 3 times
[rtsp @ 0x19b4fa0] All info found
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://192.168.193.182:5000/IcL8tHJdU9oWEK3rAAAA.sdp':
  Metadata:
    title           : IcL8tHJdU9oWEK3rAAAA
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0, 146, 1/48000: Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, mono, fltp
    Stream #0:1, 88, 1/90000: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline), 1 reference frame, yuv420p(progressive, left), 640x480, 0/1, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 60 tbc
Successfully opened the file.
Parsing a group of options: output file /opt/mediasoup_sample/recordings/IcL8tHJdU9oWEK3rAAAA.mp4.
Applying option vcodec (force video codec ('copy' to copy stream)) with argument h264.
Applying option acodec (force audio codec ('copy' to copy stream)) with argument aac.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an output file: /opt/mediasoup_sample/recordings/IcL8tHJdU9oWEK3rAAAA.mp4.
Matched encoder 'libx264' for codec 'h264'.
[file @ 0x1b7bb80] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
Successfully opened the file.
detected 1 logical cores
[graph 0 input from stream 0:1 @ 0x1b788c0] Setting 'video_size' to value '640x480'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:1 @ 0x1b788c0] Setting 'pix_fmt' to value '0'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:1 @ 0x1b788c0] Setting 'time_base' to value '1/90000'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:1 @ 0x1b788c0] Setting 'pixel_aspect' to value '0/1'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:1 @ 0x1b788c0] Setting 'sws_param' to value 'flags=2'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:1 @ 0x1b788c0] Setting 'frame_rate' to value '30/1'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:1 @ 0x1b788c0] w:640 h:480 pixfmt:yuv420p tb:1/90000 fr:30/1 sar:0/1 sws_param:flags=2
[format @ 0x1a78e00] compat: called with args=[yuv420p|yuvj420p|yuv422p|yuvj422p|yuv444p|yuvj444p|nv12|nv16]
[format @ 0x1a78e00] Setting 'pix_fmts' to value 'yuv420p|yuvj420p|yuv422p|yuvj422p|yuv444p|yuvj444p|nv12|nv16'
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x19ba180] query_formats: 4 queried, 3 merged, 0 already done, 0 delayed
[graph 1 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x1b89ae0] Setting 'time_base' to value '1/48000'
[graph 1 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x1b89ae0] Setting 'sample_rate' to value '48000'
[graph 1 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x1b89ae0] Setting 'sample_fmt' to value 'fltp'
[graph 1 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x1b89ae0] Setting 'channel_layout' to value '0x4'
[graph 1 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x1b89ae0] tb:1/48000 samplefmt:fltp samplerate:48000 chlayout:0x4
[audio format for output stream 0:1 @ 0x1a7aa00] Setting 'sample_fmts' to value 'fltp'
[audio format for output stream 0:1 @ 0x1a7aa00] Setting 'sample_rates' to value '96000|88200|64000|48000|44100|32000|24000|22050|16000|12000|11025|8000|7350'
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x1a7a6e0] query_formats: 4 queried, 9 merged, 0 already done, 0 delayed
[h264 @ 0x1b779a0] nal_unit_type: 9, nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 0x1b779a0] nal_unit_type: 7, nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1b779a0] nal_unit_type: 8, nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1b779a0] Ignoring NAL type 9 in extradata
[libx264 @ 0x1a6b5e0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 0x1a6b5e0] profile High, level 3.0
[libx264 @ 0x1a6b5e0] 264 - core 140 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2013 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=1 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to '/opt/mediasoup_sample/recordings/IcL8tHJdU9oWEK3rAAAA.mp4':
  Metadata:
    title           : IcL8tHJdU9oWEK3rAAAA
    encoder         : Lavf57.56.100
    Stream #0:0, 0, 1/15360: Video: h264 (libx264), 1 reference frame ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p(left), 640x480, 0/1, q=-1--1, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.64.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1, 0, 1/48000: Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, delay 1024, 69 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.64.100 aac
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (opus (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
    Last message repeated 1 times
[SWR @ 0x1af80a0] Using fltp internally between filters
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
    Last message repeated 48 times
[h264 @ 0x1b779a0] nal_unit_type: 5, nal_ref_idc: 3
    Last message repeated 3 times
[h264 @ 0x1b779a0] Reinit context to 640x480, pix_fmt: yuv420p
*** 67 dup!
[libx264 @ 0x1a6b5e0] frame=   0 QP=16.76 NAL=3 Slice:I Poc:0   I:1200 P:0    SKIP:0    size=29147 bytes
[libx264 @ 0x1a6b5e0] frame=   1 QP=15.49 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:8   I:1    P:198  SKIP:1001 size=588 bytes

    ... a lot of the same ...

[libx264 @ 0x1a6b5e0] frame=  25 QP=16.64 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:56  I:0    P:15   SKIP:1185 size=72 bytes
[libx264 @ 0x1a6b5e0] frame=  26 QP=27.00 NAL=2 Slice:B Poc:52  I:0    P:18   SKIP:1182 size=44 bytes
frame=   68 fps= 38 q=29.0 size=      32kB time=00:00:00.80 bitrate= 332.6kbits/s dup=67 drop=0 speed=0.453x    
[h264 @ 0x1b779a0] nal_unit_type: 9, nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 0x1b779a0] nal_unit_type: 1, nal_ref_idc: 3
    Last message repeated 3 times
[h264 @ 0x1b779a0] nal_unit_type: 9, nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 0x1b779a0] nal_unit_type: 1, nal_ref_idc: 3
    Last message repeated 3 times

    ... a lot of the same ...

*** dropping frame 68 from stream 0 at ts 64
[h264 @ 0x1b779a0] nal_unit_type: 9, nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 0x1b779a0] nal_unit_type: 1, nal_ref_idc: 3
    Last message repeated 3 times
*** dropping frame 68 from stream 0 at ts 65
[libx264 @ 0x1a6b5e0] frame=  27 QP=29.00 NAL=0 Slice:B Poc:50  I:0    P:1    SKIP:1199 size=19 bytes
[h264 @ 0x1b779a0] nal_unit_type: 9, nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 0x1b779a0] nal_unit_type: 1, nal_ref_idc: 3
    Last message repeated 3 times

    ... a lot of the same ...

[libx264 @ 0x1a6b5e0] frame= 362 QP=24.00 NAL=2 Slice:B Poc:208 I:0    P:6    SKIP:1194 size=30 bytes
[libx264 @ 0x1a6b5e0] frame= 363 QP=26.00 NAL=0 Slice:B Poc:206 I:0    P:0    SKIP:1200 size=19 bytes
[h264 @ 0x1b779a0] nal_unit_type: 1, nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1b779a0] concealing 880 DC, 880 AC, 880 MV errors in P frame
*** 1 dup!
[libx264 @ 0x1a6b5e0] frame= 364 QP=26.00 NAL=0 Slice:B Poc:210 I:0    P:0    SKIP:1200 size=19 bytes
[libx264 @ 0x1a6b5e0] frame= 365 QP=16.71 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:220 I:0    P:8    SKIP:1192 size=51 bytes
frame=  407 fps= 16 q=29.0 size=     306kB time=00:00:17.48 bitrate= 143.2kbits/s dup=329 drop=65 speed=0.675x    
[rtsp @ 0x19b4fa0] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0x19b4fa0] RTP: missed 2 packets
[h264 @ 0x1b779a0] nal_unit_type: 9, nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 0x1b779a0] nal_unit_type: 1, nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x1b779a0] concealing 920 DC, 920 AC, 920 MV errors in P frame
*** 1 dup!

    ... a lot of the same ...

[libx264 @ 0x1a6b5e0] frame= 420 QP=25.50 NAL=0 Slice:B Poc:322 I:0    P:280  SKIP:920  size=282 bytes
[libx264 @ 0x1a6b5e0] frame= 421 QP=24.51 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:326 I:0    P:43   SKIP:1157 size=112 bytes
[aac @ 0x1a79de0] Trying to remove 320 more samples than there are in the queue
frame=  422 fps=8.7 q=29.0 Lsize=     379kB time=00:00:17.54 bitrate= 176.7kbits/s dup=338 drop=65 speed=0.36x    
video:240kB audio:123kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 4.257356%
Input file #0 (rtsp://192.168.193.182:5000/IcL8tHJdU9oWEK3rAAAA.sdp):
  Input stream #0:0 (audio): 725 packets read (54182 bytes); 725 frames decoded (696000 samples); 
  Input stream #0:1 (video): 150 packets read (203332 bytes); 150 frames decoded; 
  Total: 875 packets (257514 bytes) demuxed
Output file #0 (/opt/mediasoup_sample/recordings/IcL8tHJdU9oWEK3rAAAA.mp4):
  Output stream #0:0 (video): 422 frames encoded; 422 packets muxed (245681 bytes); 
  Output stream #0:1 (audio): 680 frames encoded (696000 samples); 681 packets muxed (126146 bytes); 
  Total: 1103 packets (371827 bytes) muxed
875 frames successfully decoded, 0 decoding errors
[AVIOContext @ 0x1a6c4e0] Statistics: 60 seeks, 1148 writeouts
[libx264 @ 0x1a6b5e0] frame I:3     Avg QP:17.89  size: 17026
[libx264 @ 0x1a6b5e0] frame P:120   Avg QP:18.27  size:  1244
[libx264 @ 0x1a6b5e0] frame B:299   Avg QP:24.50  size:   149
[libx264 @ 0x1a6b5e0] consecutive B-frames:  4.7%  1.9%  1.4% 91.9%
[libx264 @ 0x1a6b5e0] mb I  I16..4: 19.9% 48.9% 31.1%
[libx264 @ 0x1a6b5e0] mb P  I16..4:  2.1%  5.2%  0.8%  P16..4: 10.3%  1.2%  0.6%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:79.7%
[libx264 @ 0x1a6b5e0] mb B  I16..4:  0.1%  0.1%  0.0%  B16..8:  5.4%  0.2%  0.0%  direct: 0.8%  skip:93.5%  L0:56.3% L1:43.1% BI: 0.5%
[libx264 @ 0x1a6b5e0] 8x8 transform intra:60.5% inter:62.3%
[libx264 @ 0x1a6b5e0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 40.2% 49.9% 19.0% inter: 0.7% 3.2% 0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x1a6b5e0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 26% 30%  9% 36%
[libx264 @ 0x1a6b5e0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 44% 27% 13%  3%  2%  2%  3%  3%  3%
[libx264 @ 0x1a6b5e0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 38% 28% 11%  3%  5%  4%  5%  4%  3%
[libx264 @ 0x1a6b5e0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 38% 28% 23% 12%
[libx264 @ 0x1a6b5e0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:2.5% UV:2.5%
[libx264 @ 0x1a6b5e0] ref P L0: 82.7%  3.3% 10.6%  3.3%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x1a6b5e0] ref B L0: 86.6% 12.6%  0.7%
[libx264 @ 0x1a6b5e0] ref B L1: 96.5%  3.5%
[libx264 @ 0x1a6b5e0] kb/s:139.34
[aac @ 0x1a79de0] Qavg: 212.691
```

Thanks,
Johnathan Kanarek

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stream RTP to FFMPEG using SDP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42900514/stream-rtp-to-ffmpeg-using-sdp)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is nothing wrong in my SDP or in the RTP packets, it plays perfectly by VLC, I'll try to use a higher version of ffmpeg but obviously the issue is with ffmpeg.